# io.netty.util.internal.bestAvailableMac on systems with complex networks

Tags: netty, mainframe

I'm running on a large mainframe system that has many different types of network adapters, including some that don't have the concept of a MAC address. Right now, Netty generally doesn't find an acceptable MAC address in this environment, so it sets the MAC to a string of random characters. This causes problems because a given system ends up with a random identity rather than one that's predictable over time.

Is there a way for me to set some type of property to explicitly tell Netty what I want to use for my MAC address? I'm thinking it would be sensible to have "-Dio.netty.Mac=*value*" to have Netty skip it's own attempt to associate a MAC address with my system...does anything like this exist today?

Comment: Do you have logging enabled and is the interface you are expecting to be found but there is no detectable MAC ?  What type of interfaces are you having issues with ?  DVIPA ?

Comment: There seem to be a handful of interfaces that normally wouldn't have MACs...an example would be a CTC, a Hipersocket connection or an interface defined as a TRLE. It's not uncommon on z/OS, but Netty seems to not be able to handle this particular situation.